# Get Action of Push Notification Allow Button

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification

I'm working on a ios Application,
now I want to get the action of push notification's allow button,
the user will be push to second view controller once user select one of push notification option(don't allow, allow).

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531103/swift-ios-check-if-remote-push-notifications-are-enabled-in-ios9-and-ios10/41911664#41911664)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531103/swift-ios-check-if-remote-push-notifications-are-enabled-in-ios9-and-ios10?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to call these methods in AppDelegate Class.

```
//Ios 10 delegates for Push Notifications
        func userNotificationCenter( _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping ( _ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void){
            print("Handle push from foreground")
        }
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void){
            print("Handle push from background or closed")
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!, Sorry but i'm unable to upvote your answer i dont have enough repuration.

Comment: No issues you can make it later.