# How many users have push notifications enabled?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

I have a SAAS product with many users. iOS + Android app.

1) Is there a way to check how many of them have push notifications enabled?

2) Can I programmatically check if they have push enabled? And if not, then I want to trigger alternative communication.

Questions apply for both iOS and Android.

Thank you.

Comment: On iOS your app can check whether it has been granted notification permissions, but the user can revoke the permissions at any time and you can't check until they run your app again.

Answer (score 0):

**For ios**

You'll have to implement a smart solution for do this job.

The initial point is identify a permission users.

As this response : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44407514/6273003

after, you can storage this information with some user identification.

and then, when you decide notificate, you must check this information.

PS : This permission is dynamic as @paulw11 said.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my answer only about iOS part
I think you need know what users get notification messages and if user don't get message, send it message with alternative chanel.
It can be do (in iOS) with Notification Extension
Just add send delivery status with api request (in your service)

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
let content = request.content
// send delivery status in your service
sendStatistic(content: request.content, onCompletion: {
    // show push with default content
    contentHandler(content)
})
```

}

Some guide with extension
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-notification-service-extensions--cms-27550
More Information about extension
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension
More Information about Notification
https://developer.apple.com/notifications/